# Spring Tool Suite / Maven deletes my .properties files

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm a relative newbie and i'm trying to build an app that accepts an external configuration file. I'm writing it with spring Tool suite and compiling it with Maven.

I have a src/main/java folder that contains the package with all my classes and a target folder that the .jar files get generated into.

I'm trying to use their guide on external configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

I will create a /config file in ./target and right-click > new > file which i'll name "application.properties." Once I try to interact with it, i'm warned right away that this is a derived file.

in application.properties, I put:

```
spring.application.name = "hello"
```

in a static class elsewhere in the file structure, I put:

```
@Value("${name}")
public static String name;
```

when I package and run the .jar, not only does it fail to retrieve the name property, but the .properties file and sometimes the /config folder get deleted!

What did I break to make Maven delete my .properties files?

Comment: You need to place it in the appropriate location in `src/` probably `src/main/resources`. The target directory will be cleaned pretty often as far as I'm aware.

Comment: where in project have you placed .properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your file in the `target` folder, then from time to time it will be deleted. The contents in the target folder are destroyed/created from time to time by Maven, because it's goal is to contain the result of your builds. When you issue a `clean package` command by example, Maven will destroy the contents in `target`, then rebuilds your app.

I believe you should create your properties file in the `scr/main` folder sou you can keep it in your project, but then you'll have to figure out how your properties file will be visible in your app's classpath

Since you are running a jar, you could add a parameter in the java command line (try checking run configurations in your IDE), adding the folder where your properties file will be kept.

Answer (score 0):

yo have to create property file into WEB-INF folder and configure the property file path and bean into `ApplicationContext.xml`.

```
<bean id="configProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location" value="WEB-INF/test-config.properties" />

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting files in the target folder does in fact delete them.

Answer (score 0):

When i removed the configuration section from my plugins, it stopped deleting the application.properties file

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <addResources>true</addResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So then I had this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```